# Naive unification of scalar QFT and GR is possible?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, renormalization, klein-gordon-equation

I am thinking on the Klein-Gordon equation with curved (non-diagonal) metrics.

Is it possible? Doesn't have it some inherent contradiction? If yes, what?

If no, what is this combined formula?

Comment: The problem is in quantizing gravity. It turns out that it's non-renormalizable so we can't treat it like a Yang-Mills theory. The problem isn't particles on curved space-time, it's the space-time itself.

Comment: The Schrödinger equation is $\mathbf{\mathrm{not}}$ relativistic. Are you referring to the Klein-Gordon equation perhaps, or Dirac equation? In which case, making the metric dynamical has already been attempted.

Comment: @JamalS You gave right, I referred to the Klein-Gordon, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relativistic Schr\:odinger equation is known as the Klein-Gordon, and is the pre-quantized version of the quantum field theory of a noninteracting scalar field.  If you attempt to couple this to general relativity, you get what is known as the Einstein-Klein Gordon equation.  If you attempt to na\:ively quantize this theory, you encounter all of the usual issues with renormalizability of the gravitational degrees of freedom.

Additionally, you run into issues when trying to impose causality conditions, since the lightcones are now dynamically determined--you have to know the gravitational field in order to know how your degrees of freedom can propogate.

Even pure gravity does not quantize cleanly due to these issues, much less before you add in a scalar field.

Comment: I thought on Klein-Gordon, thank you! This have a form in a curved spacetime?

Comment: @Koppany: sure.  Just take the Lagrangian $R + \nabla_{a}\phi\nabla^{a}\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^{2}\phi^{2} + f(\phi)$.  You won't be able to quantize the gravitational degrees of freedom for it, though.  If you just try to quantize the scalar field, you'll get what is known as semiclassical gravity.  This approach is how Stephen Hawking originally predicted Hawking radiation.